# When an observable emits one value, 2 API calls need to be performed

Tags: rxjs

```
let o$ = from(anEvent);

o$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.firstApi())
)
.subscribe(result => this.firstHandler());

o$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.secondApi())
)
.subscribe(result => this.secondHandler());
```

I tend to think I need to use `Subject` but I am not sure how.
Basically, what I need is when an event occurs, I need to call 2 APIs in parallel with different return handlers.

Comment: It seems to me that this is already a self answering question, what is it that would like to know other than a subject would work well here?

Comment: @AdrianBrand I am not sure how to get a `Subject` out of the `from` and pipe each of them differently.

Comment: Why would you need a Subject? Your code looks like it would work as it is and should do what you are looking for.

Comment: @Picci You are very correct! It is confusing that `Observable` is unicast and `Subject` is multicast.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { fromEvent, of } = rxjs;
const { switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const o$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('click'), 'click');

o$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => firstApi())
)
.subscribe(result => firstHandler(result));

o$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => secondApi())
)
.subscribe(result => secondHandler(result));

function firstApi() {
  return of('first');
}

function secondApi() {
  return of('second');
}

function firstHandler(val) {
  console.log(val);
}

function secondHandler(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your live example but do you need to unsubscribe from both?

Comment: I use the takeUntil pattern for unsubscribing. You add a takeUntil a subject called finalise and on component destroy you call finalise.next(); this unsubscribes all your subscriptions in one go.

Answer (score 0):

`fromEvent` gives you a multicast hot observable not need for `Subject`. Your logic can be written as follow

```
const first=this.firstApi().pipe(tap(result => this.firstHandler()))
const second=this.secondApi().pipe(tap(result => this.secondHandler()))
$o.pipe(mergeMap(e=>forkJoin(first,second)).subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but I don't need `forkJoin` because I don't need to wait for either of them.